# Year is missing for articles entries in elsarticle-num bibilography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle

I'm using the Elsevier article template. The problem is that bibliography article entries are not displayed as expected: the year is missing. Other entries (such as thesis) are displayed fine.

I'm using:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

One of the entries (from the `.bib` file) that is troubling me is:

```
@article{dasilva2009,
year = {2009},
author = {Lawinscky da Silva, D. M.  and de Lima., M. H. A. and Jacob, B. P.},
journal = {International journal of Modeling and Simulation for the Petroleum Industry},
month = jun,
number = {1},
title = {{Numerical Model for the Simulation of the Pipeline-Laybarge interaction in pipelaying procedures}},
volume = {3}
}
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this behaviour? If I switch to elsarticle-harv bibliography style, it lists all items fine.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in `elsarticle-num.bst` regarding the year; if I remove the `year` field leaving `month`, BibTeX raises no "there's a month but no year" warning as it should.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

elsarticle-num.bst is deprecated now. So you may use elsarticle-num-names.bst instead. You may download it from the following site:

http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Model-wise_bibliographic_style_files

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: or direct from elsevier: http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/the-elsarticle-latex-document-class (a range of bst files to download at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I just realised that River Valley does the latex development for Elsevier. Then maybe user30304's link is better

Comment: @craq: Indeed, on your link I only see the file elsarticle-num.bst and with their version of the file the years are still missing. With the file on user30304's link, the years are there.

Answer (score 4):

There's something very strange in `elsarticle-num.bst`: many functions for processing entries miss a `format.date` instruction. Since the year is fundamental information for a bibliography entry this should be regarded as a bug.

You can get around this bug by making a copy of `elsarticle-num.bst` and adding

```
format.date output
```

before each `fin.entry` in

```
FUNCTION {article}
FUNCTION {book}
FUNCTION {inbook}
FUNCTION {incollection}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
FUNCTION {proceedings}
```

However, this is only a rough workaround, as it's difficult to guess what the intentions of the developers are.